# this.setState not updating immediately, when basing setState on current state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `switch-case` statement similar to this.

```
switch (this.state.someState) {
  case "string1":
    this.setState({
      someState: "string5"
    });
    break;
  case "string2":
    this.setState({
      someState: "string6"
    });
    break;
  case "string3":
    this.setState({
      someState: "string7"
    });
    break;
  case "string4":
    this.setState({
      someState: "string8"
    });
    break;
  default:
    this.setState({
      someState: "string1"
    });
    break;
}
```

The problem is it sets state based on the previous state instead of the current state.

How do I go about in fixing this?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. It's more of a request than an immediate change - it can be batched with other calls for efficiency. Use the callback instead - the first argument is the previous state.

Comment: I advise you rewrite your code. 
`let someState;
switch (this.state.someState) {
  case "string1":
      someState = "string5";
    break;
}
this.setState({someState: someState});`

Comment: This use case is exactly the reason why setting state is asynchronous. React merges subsequent calls into one update. Maybe you don't want a callback, maybe you want to use `someState` you have previously set? Could you get it from a variable, for example?

Comment: @Andrew I tried rewriting the code like you suggested there's still a delay.

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions there's still a delay.

Comment: Can You explain, what are You trying to do with this switchcase?

Comment: I'm basically setting state for different settings.

Comment: https://ee.glitch.me/rJBdnfrXW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a few test cases, turns out the problem was elsewhere. I was using this `switch-case` to render different data. React Native has a feature which prevents unwanted rerendering if the data is similar to the previous data. Apparently this includes reversing and sorting the original data array. So I returned a new data array with `[].concat()` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous, so if you really want to do this, you should try with a callback :

```
  case "string1":
    this.setState({ someState: "string5" }, () => {
       break;
    });
```

Comment: This is not what I meant by "callback". Instead of using a switch to rely on previous state (which is a bad idea because *it's asynchronous*, you could use `this.setState(prevState => ({ someState: prevState.someState === "string1" ? "string5" : ... }))`. You're just attempting to break after an asynchronous operation, which makes no sense.